# Doing clean install of SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, installation, corrupt

I installed VS 2008, VS 2012 and the community version 2013 along with the matching SQL Servers but never needed the SQL Servers and never checked if they were properly installed.

I recently picked up SQL Server Management Studio and tried to connect to a server.

Unfortunately, it does not detect any local server, even though I have about twenty different entries in programs & apps for SQL Server related stuff including SQL Server 2012 and 2014 Express Localdb, an installation of SQL Server 2008, data-tier app frameworks, native clients, transact SQL, a couple "compact" versions, tools and what's not.

One would think that something in this mess would be recognized as a server, but apparently not so. I had an entry for SQL Server in the start menu with a nice GUI with an install DB option... that requested a server media folder (lord knows which). I tried starting manually one of the many SQL Servers (`sqlservr.exe`) from the program files folders to no avail (*I get a message about a corrupt installation*)

My DB experience is pretty much exclusively with MySQL and I am lost with all these applications that look like they should do something but don't.

I would like to have a bare bones installation that works for the following use:

- Coding Winform apps with local databases (compatible with Entity Framework)
- Allows to distribute the apps with local databases for free (commercial use, small data volume)
- Running SQL queries from SQL Server Management Studio

What is the minimum I need for this purpose?

Should I uninstall all the existing SQL Server related programs and make a clean install from a single install file (for instance, would installing the 1.1gb SQL Server 2014 Management Studio Express 64 Bit.exe give me all I need)?

Or if not, is there any way to install a recent version and ignore the underlying mess? (I don't really care for the disk space, I just want this thing to work).

I apologize if this question is a mess but I am pretty confused with this, and I could really use a hand figuring out what's what.

Comment: *SQL Server 2014 Management Studio Express 64 Bit.exe give me all I need* - ***NO!*** this is ***JUST*** the management studio - just the GUI to run queries - it is ***NO*** SQL Server database engine (the core piece you need!). Look for a SQL Server Express **with Tools** edition - this is the database engine *including* the management GUI

Comment: Sql Server runs as a service in windows. Windows service live in administrative tasks. if there is a valid SQL server install you should see it in the Services window. If you don't see it it isn't installed. If you do see it then the status column will tell you if it's running or not.If it's not running then left click to pop a dialog and start it.